# GA Universal Analytics custom dimension string as customer ID

Tags: google-analytics, universal-analytics

We're having a trouble where userId is being set as one of our custom dimensions string names (see screenshot). These strings can be "Registered", "Bidder".

The only problem I can see reading the code as far as syntax  is a comma being on the next line in the object options, which should be fine, no?

The code i'm sharing is from our test environment, so cookie is set to none!

Was hoping someone could point out our mistake, as I'm no GA expert.   Thank you in advance!

[image: screenshot from GA]

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  (function(i,s,o,g,r,a,m){
    i['GoogleAnalyticsObject']=r;i[r]=i[r] || function(){
      (i[r].q=i[r].q||[]).push(arguments)}, i[r].l=1*new Date();
    a=s.createElement(o), m=s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0];
    a.async=1;
    a.src=g;
    m.parentNode.insertBefore(a,m)
  })(window,document,'script','//www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js','ga');

  ga('create', 'FOO-CENSORED', {
    'cookieDomain': 'none'
    , 'userId': '114968'
  });

  ga('require', 'displayfeatures');
  ga('set', 'dimension4', 'true');
  ga('set', 'dimension5', 'Registered');

  ga('send', 'pageview');
</script>
```

Comment: Check on the admin, under custom definitions and then custom dimensions, what is the name of the custom dimension with index 5?

Comment: I think you are just looking at the wrong report. "User defined value" is not related to custom dimensions (in fact it's already been in the menu long before Custom Dimensions existed in GA). Custom Dimensions do not show by default in any standard report, you need to set them as second dimension or create a customized report.